# Unable to run hg due to "ImportError: No module named osutil"

Tags: python, macos, mercurial, importerror

I'm getting the following error when trying to run any hg command.

I tried to uninstall & install again XCode and the dev-tools.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 41, in <module>
mercurial.util.setbinary(fp)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 102, in __getattribute__
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 74, in _load
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 43, in _hgextimport
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 66, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 102, in __  getattribute__
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 74, in _load
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 43, in _hgextimport
ImportError: No module named osutil
```

osutil.so exist on /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial.

Answer (score 11):

osutil is part of mercurial.
Go to the folder where you downloaded mercurial and run

```
make local
```

Make sure that it runs correctly and you should be good to go.

Comment: Any advice to do this on Windows?

Comment: @Noumenon On windows use these instructions: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows

Comment: This worked for me, even though my problem was `ImportError: no module named base85`.

Comment: @CharlesB: not really clear what to do for Windows, I don't need to build mercurial on my machine...(?!)